# fast search scope not getting updated

Tags: fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint

I have two different host name for example http://contosoold and http://contosonew in content source.

Now i had created a scope to include results from "hotname=http://contosoold.com/".

In the search results page i have edited the core search webpart and given the scope name.But still i am able to see the results from both "contosoold" and "contosonew" site.

Please let me know if i am missing some step.

Thanks,

Sudan

Comment: How did you create your scope?

Comment: I had created from UI and also tried with powershell in both the case it did not work.Below is the code used while creating with power shell, after creating the scope i hve added the rule from UI.New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryScope -SearchApplication "FASTSearchQuery" -Name moss -Description "Content Source Scope" -DisplayInAdminUI 1 -ExtendedSearchFilter 'contentsource:Old System'

Comment: ExtendedSearchFilter 'contentsource="old system"' <- You have to add quotes when you have multiple words in the content source name. Also see http://searchunleashed.wordpress.com/2011/04/02/facing-the-dreaded-your-query-is-malformed-please-rephrase-your-query-when-using-fs4sp-scopes/